# Get values from a group of Angular Material checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material2

I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected values of a group of Angular (7) Material checkboxes.

Let's say I have an area on the form "flavors" and 3 checkboxes with values of "chocolate", "vanilla", and "strawberry".

```
<h3>Flavors</h3>
<mat-checkbox value="chocolate">Chocolate</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox value="vanilla">Vanilla</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox value="strawberry">Strawberry</mat-checkbox>
```

As the checkboxes are checked on and off, I want to update the variable (model) "flavorsAvailable".

It's simple to do this with mat-radio-groups, since it's just an ngModel on the group element.  But how do I manage checkboxes?

Note:  I don't want to use an Angular Material Selection list; this is just for forms.

Comment: What type is `flavorsAvailable`? What should happen to the model as you check and uncheck your checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve, a material selecion list you can use [(ngModel)]="variable" [formControl]="control" or in a form, formGroupName="property". In all case you get an array with the selected options. I don't imagine a better way to manage the checkbox.

Well you can use mat-check alone, it's only use [(ngModel)]. e.g. if you has an array of booleans. Yes, has no sense [value] in a mat-check-box, the only allowed values are: true or false

```
variable:boolean[]=[]
```

You can use

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="variable[0]" value="chocolate">Chocolate</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="variable[1]" value="vanilla">Vanilla</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="variable[2]" value="strawberry">Strawberry</mat-checkbox>
{{variable|json}}
```

Comment: Makes sense, although it is a bit odd. Also, I used `variable = []`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See if this help you:

```
flavorsAvailable: any[] = [
    { 'id': '0', 'name': 'chocolate' },
    { 'id': '1', 'name': 'vanilla' }
];

getCheckeds(ev): any[] {
  return this.flavorsAvailable.filter(x => x.state = ev.target.checked);
}
```

If this is the type of list that you did mention on "*I don't want to use an Angular Material Selection list; this is just for forms.*". Them, this don't make sense, you would need to pick one by one in 3 different ngModels...